# Fetching Orders and Orderlines Count with subqueries

Tags: c#, nhibernate, subquery, queryover

I am in process to port an old App to Nhibernate.
The old application uses ORACLE packages extensively and I want to get rid of that.
I've started to map few tables and things seem to work very well.
Now, I've got this query which I would like to be able to manage via QueryOver ... or something similar:

```
SELECT
    Orders.*
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OrderLines
        WHERE OrderLines.CompanyCode = Orders.CompanyCode
              AND OrderLines.OrderNumber = Orders.OrderNumber
              AND NOT (OrderLines.OCLSCOM = 'Y' AND OrderLines.OCLSSEQ = 0)
              AND OrderLines.Status = 'R') OrderLinesCount
    FROM
        Orders
    WHERE
        AND Orders.CompanyCode = [CompanyCode];
```

**[CompanyCode]** is a filter.

I've got to mapping files (Orders and OrderLines) and my association looks like this:

```
<class name="Order" table="Orders">
    ...
    <set name="OrderLines" access="field.pascalcase-underscore" inverse="true" lazy="extra" cascade="none">
      <key>
        <column name="OrderNumber" not-null="true"/>
        <column name="CompanyCode" not-null="true"/>
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="OrderLine" not-found ="ignore"/>
    </set>
</class>
```

The primary key for my Orders table is **CompanyCode** and **OrderNumber**.

I would like to query the Orders and fetch the number of lines for each order.

I've achieve what I want adding a formula property (thanks [Ayende](http://ayende.com/blog/3936/nhibernate-mapping-property) for that) on the Order mapping:

```
<property name="OrderLinesCount" formula="(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OrderLines WHERE OrderLines.CompanyCode = CompanyCode AND OrderLines.OrderNumber = OrderNumber AND NOT (OrderLines.OCLSCOM = 'Y' AND OrderLines.OCLSSEQ = 0) AND OrderLines.Status = 'R')" />
```

but I am scared my customer might decided to change those nasty filters one day and I would be forced to recompile the whole project.

Is there a way to achieve the same result with a subquery (QueryOver) ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: _"a way to achieve the same result with a subquery"_ >> do you mean a non-SQL subquery, or in other words, a dynamic query in code?

Comment: @Abel, I would like to get rid of the formula property and use, if possible, a subquery (QueryOver).

Comment: Keep in mind that formula is executed for each row and there is no lazy load. So performance would be terrible for large datasets

Comment: Why is it an issue to recompile whole project after changing the formula? How the change of formula differs from the QueryOver query change?

Comment: @Jakub Linhart: QueryOver gives you the ability to build expressions (criterions) dynamically. Things that I do quite often, especially in these situtations.

Comment: So you want to change the formula at runtime?

Comment: @Jakub Linhart: Yes, possibly. My customer's requirements are always "Let's put configuration parameters in files/dbs so, if I want to change something I don't have to call you!".

Comment: Then you can put your mapping files into database:]

Comment: @Jakub Linhart: Yes, that can be an idea. Anyway, I know I can do it with subqueries and QueryOver.I've almost found a solution for that. I hoped someone could have help me with that.As soon as I've got the code I'll put it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I've decided to go for the formula property:

```
<property name="OrderLinesCount" formula="(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OrderLines WHERE OrderLines.CompanyCode = CompanyCode AND OrderLines.OrderNumber = OrderNumber AND NOT (OrderLines.OCLSCOM = 'Y' AND OrderLines.OCLSSEQ = 0) AND OrderLines.Status = 'R')" />
```

One day, if I'll need to change filter I might think to use nHibernate filters.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be exactly what you are looking for but have you considered a where clause on the collection. You can call order.OrderLinesFiltered.Count to get the value

```
<set name="OrderLinesFiltered" table="OrderLines" 
access="field.pascalcase-underscore" inverse="true" lazy="extra"
cascade="none" 
where=" NOT (OCLSCOM = 'Y' AND OCLSSEQ = 0) AND Status = 'R' ">
  <key>
    <column name="OrderNumber" not-null="true"/>
    <column name="CompanyCode" not-null="true"/>
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="OrderLine" not-found ="ignore"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Yes, I know it would be executed for each row but I am going to filter the dataset so I never have more than a few rows. Yours is a good idea but I was expecting something different cause, as I said, my customer might ask me to filter in a different way one day.